# Attach a file in an email

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

I want to send a file as an attachement with the email sent from my laravel application. this is how I tried to attach the file

```
  $path = Storage::url($this->newsletter["file"]);

  Mail::send(new NewsLetterEmail($this->newsletter), [], function ($message) use ($path) {
        $message->attach($path);
  });
```

But the email is being sent with no attachment. How can I attach a file to the email?

Comment: I think you should have the `storage_path()` instead of `Storage::url()`

Comment: well, I tried it now and it returns the same result.

Comment: this is the result of my storage_path outputs: /home/username/public_html/backend/storage//files/fyJ2jREuCGVC85fn.pdf

Comment: it did work now.
when I wrote: $path = public_path() . Storage::url($newsletter["media"]) but not using storage_path helper function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `storage_path()` that will point to the file in `storage` path, then you can do so

```
 Mail::send(new NewsLetterEmail($this->newsletter), [], function ($message) use ($path) {
    $message->attach($path);
 });
```

if you need to change the attached file name or add the file mime type you can add

```
 Mail::send(new NewsLetterEmail($this->newsletter), [], function ($message) use ($path) {
    $message->attach($path, [
       'as' => 'Attached file name',
       'mime' => 'Attached file mime type',
    ]);
 });
```

Comment: well, I tried it now and it returns the same result.

Comment: this is the result of my storage_path outputs: /home/username/public_html/backend/storage//files/fyJ2jREuCGVC85fn.pdf

Comment: are you sure that the file existed there and readable? because the code looks ok and it should work fine.

Comment: it did work now
when I wrote: $path = public_path() . Storage::url($newsletter["media"]) but not using storage_path helper function